# Where this gap comes from and how to get rid off it?

Tags: html, css, image, margin, gaps-in-visuals

Simple code:

```
<a href="#">
    <div>
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=image" class="image" />
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x15/000/fff" alt="" class="shadow" />
    </div>
</a>
```

Two images have margin and padding of 0 but there's still a gap between them.

How to avoid this behavior?

And YES that's not a mistake, the whole thing has to be in A tag.

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/fqrfU/

Comment: why the extra div? you don't need an extra div container for that

Comment: @corroded, in fact I do, my real code is much more complicated (several divs after and before images) :)

Comment: hmm, i mean, are they used as containers? or for styling purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two images are displayed inline. This means the baseline of the image is aligned with the baseline of the text. Below text there usually is some more space to account for letters like `pjgq` that go below the baseline.

Just making the images `display: block;` resolves this in your scenario.

This page describes your situation quite clearly: http://devedge-temp.mozilla.org/viewsource/2002/img-table/

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's the line-height that's causing the problem. [Check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/fqrfU/6/).

On a different note, I know you said it was intended to be that way but it's actually invalid(?) HTML to have the `div` tag inside of the anchor. Try using `span`s instead.

Comment: If using a HTML5 doctype, it's perfectly valid. See http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/ for reference

Comment: Oh man, thanks for pointing that out @Luke. Didn't realize it.

Answer (score 1):

add in both `display:block;`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fqrfU/22/

Answer (score 0):

You can float and clear them:

```
img {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lukemartin/fqrfU/11/

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#">
    <div>
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=image" class="image" /><img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x15/000/fff" alt="" class="shadow" />
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you having a problem in IE?
Try putting both images tags on the same line in the HTML, w/o any spaces in between...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me just now:

```
img
{  
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply your css by doing,

```
.image, .shadow {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display:block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fqrfU/43/

Answer (score 0):

What Bogdan said, or:

`<div>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=image" class="image" /><img 
        src="http://dummyimage.com/600x15/000/fff" alt="" class="shadow" />
 </div>
</a>`

See, the whitespace between `/>` and the second  `<img` is actually rendered, which gives the space between the two pics.

-- pete